# Indents in nested lists in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I've started using Twitter Bootstrap, which is useful for me (as a programmer) to get a decent looking site without having to write much CSS.

However something is driving me crazy. I have a nested list like

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World 
    <ul>
      <li>Wide</li>
      <li>Web</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But the first and second level of this list are NOT getting indented differently (ie. they align with each other on the left)

In normal html nested lists, deeper sublists indent more. But something in the style sheet must be turning this off. How do I find what controls this? I can't see a CSS "list indent" attribute for li elements in any documentation.

Comment: Can you reproduce in JSFiddle. Your code with the twitter bootstrap works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3hHwF/

Answer (score 26):

Just use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in FF or [Chrome dev-tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html): right-click on your target and `select inspect` element. You can visually and textually inspect the CSS properties to see what's causing the collapse.

You probably want a rule  like

```
ul > li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to the answers above: `padding-left` will indent the words, but not the bullet point, while `margin-left` will indent the bullet point as well.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GMLxv/

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you.

There's a rule in type.less that cancels the indentation for lists:

```
ul, ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 @baseLineHeight / 2 25px;
}
```

I ended up overriding this rule:

```
ul, ol {
  padding: 0px 25px;
}
```

Indentation in nested lists is now back.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking to set `padding-left`:

```
li { padding-left: 1em; }
```

will indent every li 1em. Since the inner lis are already offset from the outer lis, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You **wouldn't** want to apply the padding onto the `li` elements since that would create a padding between the bullet and the list if you are using a bulleted list. See:

```
ul > li {
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

result:

```
-    Hello
-    World 
    -    Wide
    -    Web
```

Neither would you want to apply it to the parent `ul` elements with `ul { padding-left:25px;}` which would give:

```
    - Hello 
    - World 
        - Wide
        - Web
```

The answer to your question is:

```
li > ul {
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

result:

```
- Hello
- World 
    - Wide
    - Web
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it perhaps that you have set your bullets points to be inside the list items instead of before it, which would change your look quite significantly.

The CSS to apply it: `ul { list-style-position: inside; }`

Read more about [list-style-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp).

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/g0k0obwh/

Comment: It could be that some style is setting this to the one or the other... just apply your explicit settings perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap you could do that by coding as follows. Just paste it your JSP or HTML and test it. You could go through this link for more information.

http://www.bootply.com/DglnYJTSKA

```
   <div id="MainMenu">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 3</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
            <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu1">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 a</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 2 b</a>
              <a href="#SubSubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Subitem 3 c <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu list-group-submenu-1" id="SubSubMenu1">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 2</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 4 d</a>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 4</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
           <a href="#demo5" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 5</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo5">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-group.panel > .list-group-item {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
.list-group-submenu {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```